# Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: magento, cart, magento-rules

I am running a store where I have two product categories(Category A, Category B).
Category A has one product(Product A)
Category B has three products(Product1, Product2, Product3).

I wish to set the rule such that when a customer buys "ProductA" from Category A and Product3 From category B, a discount of $8.75 is applied to the "Product3". I tried to find solutions but all in vain. Can anyone please help me out in this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That pretty easy. Go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes. [image]

Find SKU at Attribute Code

[image]

Change Promo Rule Conditions to Yes from No.

We done first step :)

Then go again to your shopping cart prices rules.

1. Define your rule name and blar blar blar at Rule Information. Then, Click on Condition
2. Click to (+) Button. Then, Chose ***Product attribute combination***
3. Then, new (+) Button appear and click this.
4. Choose Category and find your category (e.g Category A or Category B)
5. Will see like this. [image]
6. Then, new (+) Button appear and click this.
7. Chose SKU for your Product A or B. See picture. [image]
8. Then Click again from start for your next Category and product.
9. Finally, we got next. See pic [image]

Hope help O). Magento make me happy!!!